# FFmpeg change overlay color (with audiovisualiser)

Tags: ffmpeg

There is a padding (default black) under the audio visualiser in the script below ,how could one change the color of this padding ? 
[image]I tried adding option "overlay :colors= Blue" but received an error= "Option 'colors' not found"

> fmpeg -y -i music.mp3 -loop 1 -i whiteImage.jpg -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x175:colors=Red:mode=p2p,format=yuv420p[v];[1:v][v]overlay=0:200[outv]" -map "[outv]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest output_bg.mp4

Answer (score 1):

Use

`ffmpeg -y -i music.mp3 -loop 1 -i image -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x175:colors=Red:mode=p2p,format=yuva420p,split=2[w][b];[b]format=yuv420p,drawbox=c=blue:t=fill[b];[b][w]overlay[wv];[1:v][wv]overlay=0:200:shortest=1[outv]" -map "[outv]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output_bg.mp4`

The showwaves will make the background transparent if the filter can output to a frame format with alpha. `yuv420p` does not have alpha, so the value of the format filter should be changed to a format that does, like `yuva420p`. Then this picture is cloned; one copy is made opaque and has a color drawn on it. The other copy with the transparent BG is overlaid on top. Finally, this result is overlaid on the image.

It's better to limit the video stream within the overlay filter, if possible. So, `-shortest` removed.

Comment: thanks for the script but  running it, gives the following error :-Stream specifier 'v' in filtergraph description [0:a]showwaves=s=1280x175:colors=Red:mode=p2p,format=yuva420p,split=2[w][b];[b]format=yuv420p,drawbox=c=blue:t=fill[b];[b][v]overlay[wv];[1:v][wv]overlay=0:200:shortest=1[outv] matches no streams.